# Is it possible to destructure a type definition in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I was playing with the `Babel` package and noticed that most other `Babel` packages are included in `@babel/core`. Originally I had the following imports:

```
import babel from '@babel/core';

import type {
  ImportDeclaration,
  ObjectProperty,
  ObjectExpression,
  StringLiteral,
} from '@babel/types';
```

But in fact, `babel.types` is `@babel/types`. I was thinking that I could remove the `@babel/types` to have one less dependency. This is how I was able to do it:

```
import babel from '@babel/core';

type ImportDeclaration = babel.types.ImportDeclaration;
type ObjectProperty = babel.types.ObjectProperty;
type ObjectExpression = babel.types.ObjectExpression;
type StringLiteral = babel.types.StringLiteral;
```

This feels more verbose than the original version. Would there be a way to do something like this instead?

```
type {
  ImportDeclaration,
  ObjectProperty,
  ObjectExpression,
  StringLiteral,
} = babel.types;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no support for destructuring types the way you can currently do with values.

There is a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#13135](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13135) requesting such functionality.  You may want to go to that issue and give it a  and/or describe your use case if you think it's compelling.  But I don't see any indication that it will be implemented in the foreseeable future.  For now you will probably want to keep using the methods that work, despite their relative verbosity.